# Import manually created K8s cluster into KOps

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, terraform, kops

It's been sometime I've visited all the web pages carrying word "KOps import" but did not find a way to import my manually created K8s cluster. Manually created cluster means "*Deployed Infra on AWS using Terraform and Kubernetes using Terraform's provisioner script as Shell script*". Now as I see managing the environment manually is a pain, I look forward to move it under KOps. For that I have done the following so far:

1. Installed `aws cli`, `kubectl` and `kops` in my local machine.
2. Created KOps user with policies `AmazonEC2FullAccess`,
   `AmazonRoute53FullAccess`, `AmazonS3FullAccess`, `IAMFullAccess`,
   `AmazonVPCFullAccess` and generated access and secret keys.
3. Configured credentials using `aws configure`.
4. Created S3 bucket to store state.
5. Set env variables like Region and Cluster name.
6. Finally, ran kops import command as below:

   `kops import cluster --region` `${REGION}` `--name` `${OLD_NAME}`

But encountered below error:

```
Cluster.kops "jjm-prod-use1-kubernetes" not found
```

**Verbosed:**

```
$ kops import cluster --region ${REGION} --name ${OLD_NAME} -v 10
I0131 16:32:12.059651   25683 factory.go:68] state store s3://kops-state-store-jjm
I0131 16:32:13.133145   25683 s3context.go:194] found bucket in region "us-east-1"
I0131 16:32:13.133174   25683 s3fs.go:220] Reading file "s3://kops-state-store-jjm/jjm-prod-use1-kubernetes/config"
```

Which made me serious about posting this question. Is there any possible way where a K8s cluster created except using kubeup.sh can be brought under the control of KOps ? Please advise.

Note: There's no way I can re-create (destroy and create) the clusters as they are running in production.

EDIT: I know this can be achieved only the cluster was setup using kubeup.sh. But is there any other way ?

Answer (score 0):

That is only possible with cluster bootstrapped via `kube-up.sh` script as officialy announced in [Kops](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/cli/kops_import.md) documentation pages. Actually, `kube-up.sh` has been excluded from the list of supported Kubernetes installation [tools](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/turnkey/aws/) for AWS. Although, cluster composed by `kube-up.sh` provides a lot of customization settings which are specifically applicable to AWS, the initial script uses environmental variables to define these settings. Therefore, I assume that it's quite hard to achieve in your case.

Comment: Exactly! But I was wondering if there's any way. After trying all possible options it looks like there's only one solution to this i.e. recreating the cluster. :(